# Why is background-image having more priority in the CSS than inline background-color?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was trying to override a pre-defined background-image in a CSS with an inline background-color thinking it would actually override, but it looks it doesn't. How can I achieve this?

```css
.section {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background-image: url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/36487/above-adventure-aerial-air.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="section" style="background-color: rgb(250, 40, 38)">
  
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Because background image always displays "covering" the background color.  Add `background-image: none` to your inline styles and you're good to go.

Comment: you can also use `background` inline instead of `background-color`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Worked for me.

```css
.section {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background-image: url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/36487/above-adventure-aerial-air.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="section" style="background-image:none; background-color: rgb(250, 40, 38)">
  
</div>
```

Comment: yes, thanks everyone, i will use this one, is more convenient for my case.

Answer (score 3):

https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-color

> *This property sets the background color of an element. The color is drawn **behind** any background images.*

Answer (score 2):

You can have both `background-color` and `background-image`. If you want to override the `background-image` you need to do this with `background: rgb(250, 40, 38)`.

As for the WHY:

you have these background properties:

```
background-image
background-repeat
background-color
background-size
```

etc.

Now if you set `background` you include all these properties so you can specify this:

```
background-image: url(image.jpg)
```

or `background-color: rgb(250, 40, 38)`

or `background: rgb(250, 40, 38)`

This last one will assume there is no image because it is not specified in `background` and will thus override it with the specified background color

Answer (score 1):

Just set background-image:none;

eg;

```css
.section {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background-image: url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/36487/above-adventure-aerial-air.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="section" style="background-image:none; background-color: rgb(250, 40, 38)">
  
</div>
```

EDIT: The reason image has higher priority is if you want to use an image but an object can extend beyond the image size (and you have repeat set to none) then the background-color fills the rest of the space.

Comment: the "why" is image and color are 2 different attributes, and an element can have both.

The image has priority, but if the image isn't big enough, the color is then seen in excess of the image size (why both are supported)

You can override image as shown, or by just using "background: rgb(250,40,38)" which, by lack of an image url attribute, implies no image.

I gave my example of explicitly over-riding the background-image property

Comment: makes sense! :) now i get it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that you need to both add your css for the new colour but also the styling for the background image itself.

If you are wanting to hide the image so that your colour will come through and be visible add

```html
<div class="section" style="background-color: rgb(250, 40, 38);background-image:none;">
  
</div>
```

That should do the trick. :) Hope this helps

Comment: This does not answer the *why* part of the question, though, does it...

Comment: I guess not but I noticed the previous comment already sent them the w3c URL for reference in that regard. :) In the end they also asked how they can achieve this so I provided the answer. no biggie :)

Answer (score 1):

Use **background** instead of *background-image* and *background-color* :

```
.section {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background: url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/36487/above-adventure-aerial-air.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}

<div class="section" style="background: rgb(250, 40, 38)">
```

**and it will work!**

Answer (score 1):

The spec was written with progressive enhancement in mind:

> Use background image, to display an image, and background color as a fallback for older browsers.

Comment: Where is that quote from, sir? Who said that quote, or what document does the quote come from?