# Relative path for a background image

Tags: css, background-image

I'm trying to get a background image on a website but can't get the relative path correct.

Here is the generic code from w3 schools:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body  {
  background-image: url("paper.gif");
  background-color: #cccccc;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>The background-image Property</h1>

<p>Hello World!</p>

</body>
</html>
```

I have tried using src in place of url and it is not working.

Comment: You have not provided sufficient information for anyone to recognize or comprehend what the actual problem is.

Comment: Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-color

Comment: The reference I added shows example of relative paths in the url.

Comment: This question gets asked so many times on SO every single day--and all over the internet--that there should be a big sticky button here.

Answer (score 0):

Static content such as images, css and script is typically placed in a folder for those things like an `images` folder or a `content/images` folder etc.  If that folder is in the SAME folder as your page you can reference is as for example `./images/myimage.png` or perhaps a `../../images/myimage.png` to go back two levels or `/content/images/myimage.png` if it is in a root "content" folder.

Answer (score -1):

Well, the order here is important that's why `background-color` will override the `background-image` so you have to order them like this:

```
background-color: #cccccc;
background-image: url("./paper.gif");
```

Comment: If properly written and sourced a background image displays covering the background color ref: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41885070/125981

Comment: Consider for example an image with transparency to show the color through that transparency.